# After taking a long break from lifting, what weight should you start back up with?

Tags: weightlifting

I recently took a long break from weight lifting (~1 year) for a variety of reasons. The program I was focused on started with a 5x5 of the major lifts at 80% of my 1rm. I recently started the same program, but didn't know what percentage to start at. 80% of my previous 1rm would no longer be accurate.

What is a good way to calculate where to start at? Some ideas I had were:

- 50% of my previous 1rm
- 80% of my previous 80%

Comment: How long had you been training before you took a year off?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov 4 years

Answer (score 4):

A year is a long time. Your muscles might still be strong enough for 50% of your previous 1rm but maybe your joints aren't. Or maybe you're unable to brace properly. There is just a lot of unknown here.

I think you should treat yourself as a beginner who is going to make seriously fast gains. First session, just start with high reps (20+) and an empty bar. Evaluate yourself as you perform the reps. Am I still maintaining proper form? Am I breathing correctly? Am I bracing correctly? And then sleep on it and see how your body feels the next day. If all is good, add 10-20 pounds to the lifts in the next session and once again assess yourself as you perform the reps. I would also add some accessory core exercises.

I don't think you will miss out much by giving yourself a few weeks to ease back in. Reducing the risk of injury is much more important.